# Python 3x - Error: “object” is no defined em lista

Tags: python, python-3.x

estou aprendendo a programar em python e estou com esse seguinte problema em um exercício. Ao rodar o código acontece este seguinte erro:

```
vogal = (a,e,i,o,u) 
NameError: name 'a' is not defined.
```

Ja tentei resolver digitando alguns outros códigos, escrevendo o mesmo código de outras formas e mesmo assim continuo com o erro.

```
    vogal = [a,e,i,o,u]

    letra = input("Digite uma letra: ")

    if letra in vogal:

    print('esta letra é uma vogal')

else:

print('esta letra não é uma vogal')
```

Comment: Se a intenção era que a,e,i,o,u fossem strings, valores literais, coloque os mesmos entre aspas: ```vogal = ["a","e","i","o","u"]```

Comment: Opa, deu certo, muito obrigado, não tinha prestado atenção neste pequeno detalhe. acabei achando que era um problema mais complicado mas não. Abraços

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O correto seria:

```
vogal = ('a','e','i','o','u')
```

O motivo é que, em Python (e em linguagens de programação no geral), quando você deseja utilizar uma string ela deve ser digitada entre aspas.

Sem utilizar as aspas a palavra digitada será entendida como uma variável, e não existe variável **a** declarada no seu código.